# If a hot air source was added to the wingtips, would it help control the formation of wingtip vortexes?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, winglets, wing-tip-vortex

Let's say that somehow, an engineer made an exhaust pipe that constantly sprayed hot air at the wingtips in order to help control the formation of less turbulent wingtip vortexes.

Would that have any meaningful effect?

[image: Illustration showing how the difference in pressure under and above the wing generated wingtip vortex]

The difference in pressure between the lower part of the wing (high pressure) and the top part of the wing (low pressure) allows the wing to fly, and also generates the wingtip vortex (if I didn't understood it incorrectly).

So, if you add hot air at the wingtips, it could probably allow the formation of wingtip vortex away from the wingtips... Or not.

Comment: Given that the air temp at cruise altitude is ~(-44C°), what would be the benefit of said "sprayed" air being "hot"?

Comment: How according to you would hot air reduce wingtip vortices?

Comment: I edited the text to add: "The difference in pressure between the lower part of the wing (high pressure) and the top part of the wing (low pressure) allows the wing to fly, and also generates the wingtip vortex (if I didn't understood it incorrectly)."

Comment: Some designs have *propellers* there, others winglets (including wing tip washout) or fuel tanks.  But the best way to handle it is lower AoA and greater speed.  Not unlike a power boat going fast enough that it's turbulent wake never catches up .

Comment: By what mechanism do you think that this might possibly work?  Is this simply a random "what if" idea with nothing to suggest that it would in fact work, or is there some reason that you think that it might?

Comment: @RalphJ FWIW, something similar to a bleed air lines from an engine's exhaust (just aft of the last power turbine disc) *could* be a logical source of hot air, but running that hot air through the wings (where the fuel tanks are) may not pass the 'sniff test' during engineering design review.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Okay so let's assume that the engineers somehow negotiate that hot air supply through the wing. Now how would it reduce wingtip vortices? am I missing something?

Comment: @AdityaSharma Yes, you are missing something. I was directing a comment to RalphJ. And no, handwaving that bit isn't a valid assumption.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm sorry, I meant that everyone here including you is talking about the logistics of having hot air supplied to the wingtips, but I don't get the aerodynamics of it. How does hot air reduce wingtip vortices to begin with? Nobody seems to be questioning that, so I got confused and asked you. Good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a short "feasibility study", off the top of my head:

- To resist such high temperatures, the structure should be made of some exotic titanium or stainless steel alloy which would add cost and possibly weight i.e. drag.
- The exhaust pipe spraying hot gases would add complexity and weight i.e. drag.
- Removing the low pressure (suction) from the top of the wing would simply kill the lift there since the biggest part of the lift just derives from the underpressure over the wing.
- If the exhaust still posseses high pressure, this can be converted in additional speed and thrust simply prolonging the exhaust (convergent) pipe.
- Tip vortex forms... well, at the tip of the wing; if they form away from the tip they wouldn't be tip vortex anymore :)

Anyway, tip vorteces are not that evil phenomenon as normally presented by the (marketing departments of the) airplane's manufacturers. Without entering into much detail (there are already many good explanations here about it), tip vorteces are just one piece of the big puzzle about a finite-span wing generating lift; if a wing is generating lift then it is also generating vorteces, due to Newton's second and third laws (aka momentum conservation). Indeed, vorteces are released downstream *from the entire trailing edge* of the wing, not just from the tips. The following picture ([source](https://Source:%20https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/0%5C*2gL-QOXqx51qNdAE.jpg)) schematically represents this:

[image: A more correct representation of the "tip" vortices]

In particular, the strength of each of these vorteces is proportional to the spanwise variation of lift. For a conventional jetliner trying to reduce drag, lift is distributed from tip to tip with a shape as elliptical as possible in order to minimise that part of the drag termed induced drag (aka drag due to lift). Which such elliptical spanwise lift distribution, the biggest variation of lift happen towards the tips and that's why the biggest vorteces form at the tips. Anyway this is nothing bad, on the contrary it actually shows that the lift is distributed in such a way as to minimise drag.

Comment: I still don't get how hot air will reduce the wingtip vortices . Would it somehow remove the low pressure over the wing? (if that's what is to be achieved, you might as well remove the wing from there)

Comment: @AdityaSharma: well, I only did a short feasibility study; if it really happens, that I don't know ;)

Comment: Alright, good day!

Comment: To get enough flow to make a difference somehow, you might as well just point it aft with a nozzle to offset the drag with added thrust instead.  Like, say, the engine's own tailpipe.

Comment: @JohnK, I was thinking the exact same thing!